# Does RapidAPI have an API?

Tags: api

I don't want to use their dashboard to find an API, I want to build my own search tool to find an API I may want to use.

I don't see any info indicating that they have an API for their API collection, so I'm wondering if I'm overlooking it, or if they just don't have one.

Answer (score 0):

I believe RapidAPI doesn't have any such API using which you can fetch the collection of all APIs available on RapidAPI Hub.